# WSO2 API manager - jwt protected endpoint exposing

Tags: jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

There is a backend service which is protected. In order to access need to provide user name and password and then generate jwt token. username & password can be dynamic based on the users. How is this possible to expose this using wso2 apim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to implement the solution using custom grant type. Extended this "AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler" class and override validateGrant method. While allowing the grant I have generated the backend jwt and pass it to a custom response header.

```
 @Override
public boolean validateGrant(OAuthTokenReqMessageContext oAuthTokenReqMessageContext)  throws IdentityOAuth2Exception {

    log.debug("Custom jwt Grant handler is hit");

    // extract request parameters
    RequestParameter[] parameters = oAuthTokenReqMessageContext.getOauth2AccessTokenReqDTO().getRequestParameters();

    String username = null;
    String password = null;
    String email = null;

    for(RequestParameter parameter : parameters){
        if(CUSTOM_JWT_GRANT_PARAM_USERNAME.equals(parameter.getKey())){
            if(parameter.getValue() != null && parameter.getValue().length > 0){
                username = parameter.getValue()[0];
            }
        }
        else if(CUSTOM_JWT_GRANT_PARAM_PASWORD.equals(parameter.getKey())){
            if(parameter.getValue() != null && parameter.getValue().length > 0){
                password = parameter.getValue()[0];
            }
        }
        else if(CUSTOM_JWT_GRANT_PARAM_EMAIL.equals(parameter.getKey())){
            if(parameter.getValue() != null && parameter.getValue().length > 0){
                email = parameter.getValue()[0];
            }
        }
    }

    if(username != null) {
        //validate backend username/password
        ResponseHeader responseHeader = new ResponseHeader();
        String token = generateBackendToken(username, password, email);
        if(token !=null) {
            log.debug("backend token generation success");
            // if valid set authorized username as grant user
            AuthenticatedUser jwtUser = new AuthenticatedUser();
            jwtUser.setUserName(username);
            responseHeader.setKey(CUSTOM_HEADER_BACKEND_TOKEN);
            responseHeader.setValue(token);
            oAuthTokenReqMessageContext.setAuthorizedUser(jwtUser);
            oAuthTokenReqMessageContext.setScope(oAuthTokenReqMessageContext.getOauth2AccessTokenReqDTO().getScope());
            oAuthTokenReqMessageContext.addProperty(RESPONSE_HEADERS, new ResponseHeader[]{responseHeader});
        } else{
            log.debug("backend token generation failed");
            responseHeader.setKey(CUSTOM_HEADER_BACKEND_TOKEN);
            responseHeader.setValue(CUSTOM_HEADER_BACKEND_TOKEN_INVALID);
            oAuthTokenReqMessageContext.addProperty(RESPONSE_HEADERS, new ResponseHeader[]{responseHeader});
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing a class mediator(https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/next/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/adding-a-class-mediator/). Implement a class mediator with a cache. Using that you can read username and password. Then generate JWT token and store against the username. Then next request you can get the token from the cache.

Comment: in that case do I have to pass username, password with each api call?

Comment: Yes, you can pass that in request header.

Comment: thanks chashika. I'll try this and let you know. One question, when using chace will it be a problem in a clustered environment?

Comment: I think it won't be any problem